# cant loop through array with ajax_command_html

Tags: ajax

im beginner in drupal and i would like to ask why is this not looping , it just gives me first result

```
$string = $form_state['values']['search_block_form'];

  $query=db_select('node','n');
$query->join('field_data_body','b' , 'n.nid = b.entity_id');

$query
->fields('n',array('nid', 'title'))
->fields('b', array('entity_id', 'body_value'));



  $db_or = db_or();
  $db_or->condition('n.title', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE');
  $db_or->condition('b.body_value', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE');
  $query->condition($db_or);

  $result = $query->execute();

while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
      $node_title = $row['title'];
      $node_id = $row['nid'];
      $entity_id = $row['entity_id'];
      $body_text = $row['body_value']; 


  $commands[] = ajax_command_html("#block-system-main", "<h1> $node_title </h1> <p> $body_text </p>"  );
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands); 

}
```

I want replace div with id block-system-main with found content

Comment: `$result` is result of query statement ?

Comment: yes im pulling data from input string

Comment: This is not Drupal, this is basic coding: You are getting only 1 result because you are `return`ing on the very first iteration (inside) of the `while` loop

Comment: Ok just add your code snippet  to the question not post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
  $string = $form_state['values']['search_block_form'];

  $query = db_select('node', 'n');
  $query->join('field_data_body', 'b', 'n.nid = b.entity_id');

  $query
    ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
    ->fields('b', array('entity_id', 'body_value'));

  $db_or = db_or();
  $db_or->condition('n.title', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE');
  $db_or->condition('b.body_value', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE');
  $query->condition($db_or);

  $results = $query
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $commands = [];

  foreach ($results as $result) {
    $node_title = $result['title'];
    $node_id = $result['nid'];
    $entity_id = $result['entity_id'];
    $body_text = $result['body_value'];
    $commands[] = ajax_command_html("#block-system-main", "<h1>" . $node_title . "</h1> <p>" . $body_text . "</p>");
  }
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```

Comment: now its returning only last result of the loop :(

Comment: i have tested it, did you print the `$results`  variable . so if it return only one result so there is only one result ?

Comment: yes , it returned me more results

Comment: maybe its always #block-system-main overwrited or i dont know what

Comment: Can you please mention, where you put this code ??

Comment: yes sir , of course

Comment: ok i edited it , you have my whole code

Comment: ok i have figured it out :) thanks for help , im gonna share the code in the first contribution, i was overwriting the html id every time.

Comment: great, next time, don't edit your question with the working code, but let the question as it is, and post an answer or mark someone else answer as the correct one, in case someone in the future come a cross the same case as you will get the right answer. good luck.

Comment: oh yes, my bad :/ , it wont happen again, thanks for advice

Comment: It's okay, you are welcome, it happens.